Problem refreshing a dashboard in PowerBI desktop
When I update the dashboard on the work network they work correctly, but if I connect via VPN and try to update the dashboard I get this error:

Microsoft SQL target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context.

If I update each table one by one it works fine, that's when I try to update the entire dashboard.
I have removed the computer from the domain, changed its name, rejoined it to the domain and the same error still appears.
I have created a udl file and tested the connection via SPN "Sql Server Instance/server name" and it works correctly. Has anyone had a similar problem?
